# Upload file via curl

Tags: linux, curl

I have been trying to upload a file to our SharePoint server for a couple of weeks with no success. I have read several post on here and elsewhere but I cannot see to get it to work.

These are the commands I have been trying with the outputs. Please, can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
curl -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0" -O --user domain/username:password -T failed.csv https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testwebhook/Shared%20Documents/General/failed.csv -vvv


  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to mysite.sharepoint.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to mysite.sharepoint.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.sharepoint.com,OU=Microsoft Corporation,O=Microsoft Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=WA,C=US
*       start date: Mar 07 21:35:03 2018 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 06 21:35:03 2020 GMT
*       common name: *.sharepoint.com
*       issuer: CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 1,OU=Microsoft IT,O=Microsoft Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=Washington,C=US
* Server auth using Basic with user 'domain/username'
> PUT /sites/testwebhook/Shared%20Documents/General/failed.csv HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic c3BvcnRwZXNhLmNvbS9waGlsLmJyYWR5QDp6R0FWYnRmN2Y2Z1FjbEJFdG9Udw==
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
> Host: mysite.sharepoint.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1633
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [data not shown]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Length: 272
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testwebhook/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2Fsites%2Ftestwebhook%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2Ffailed%2Ecsv
< P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
< X-SharePointHealthScore: 2
< SPRequestGuid: fa84a49e-e046-0000-38b8-14009af2f9eb
< request-id: fa84a49e-e046-0000-38b8-14009af2f9eb
< MS-CV: nqSE+kbgAAA4uBQAmvL56w.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.8314
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 60B7BACBCB0F48ADB6510D0754726C3E Ref B: LON21EDGE0609 Ref C: 2018-11-21T11:58:29Z
< Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2018 11:58:29 GMT
<
* Ignoring the response-body
{ [data not shown]
100  1905  100   272  100  1633    940   5644 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5650
* Connection #0 to host mysite.sharepoint.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testwebhook/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2Fsites%2Ftestwebhook%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2Ffailed%2Ecsv'
* Found bundle for host mysite.sharepoint.com: 0x11eb340
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host mysite.sharepoint.com
* Connected to mysite.sharepoint.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'domain:'
> PUT /sites/testwebhook/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%2Fsites%2Ftestwebhook%2FShared%20Documents%2FGeneral%2Ffailed%2Ecsv HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic c3BvcnRwZXNhLmNvbS9waGlsLmJyYWR5QDp6R0FWYnRmN2Y2Z1FjbEJFdG9Udw==
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0
> Host: mysite.sharepoint.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1633
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [data not shown]
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
< P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
< X-SharePointHealthScore: 2
< SPRequestGuid: fa84a49e-f044-0000-38b8-1bd5894edf98
< request-id: fa84a49e-f044-0000-38b8-1bd5894edf98
< MS-CV: nqSE+kTwAAA4uBvViU7fmA.0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 15
< SPIisLatency: 2
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.8314
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 3DB34D91446A4556978DF6B7BABD5907 Ref B: LON21EDGE0609 Ref C: 2018-11-21T11:58:29Z
< Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2018 11:58:29 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
100  1633    0     0  100  1633      0   4842 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4842
* Connection #0 to host mysite.sharepoint.com left intact
```

AND

```
curl --ntlm --user domain/username:password -T failed.csv https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/testwebhook/Shared-Documents/General/failed.csv -vvv
* About to connect() to mysite.sharepoint.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to mysite.sharepoint.com (13.107.136.9) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.sharepoint.com,OU=Microsoft Corporation,O=Microsoft Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=WA,C=US
*       start date: Mar 07 21:35:03 2018 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 06 21:35:03 2020 GMT
*       common name: *.sharepoint.com
*       issuer: CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 1,OU=Microsoft IT,O=Microsoft Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=Washington,C=US
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'domain/username'
> PUT /sites/testwebhook/Shared-Documents/General/failed.csv HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAABoIIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: mysite.sharepoint.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 0
> Expect: 100-continue
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
< SPRequestGuid: 4786a49e-803d-0000-38b8-19cb846bfe9d
< request-id: 4786a49e-803d-0000-38b8-19cb846bfe9d
< MS-CV: nqSGRz2AAAA4uBnLhGv+nQ.0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 65
< SPIisLatency: 2
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.8314
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 5387A1C54284471AA82105ED1FBDC2B1 Ref B: LON21EDGE1107 Ref C: 2018-11-21T12:21:13Z
< Date: Wed, 21 Nov 2018 12:21:12 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host mysite.sharepoint.com left intact
```